# reading message once subscribed to a topic

Tags: ros, rospy, topic, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am new to ROS, i have done the tutorials.
But i am a bit unsure on how to read messages (in code)

If i have a ros node which has subscribed to a topic /LaserScan see bellow
std_msgs/Header header
float32 angle_min
float32 angle_max
float32 angle_increment
float32 time_increment
float32 scan_time
float32 range_min
float32 range_max
float32[] ranges
float32[] intensities

And I am in my call back function, def callback_lidar(data):

how do i access an individual variables, like the list ranges

would i do
array = data.ranges?

I cant create the node an test it out since the lidar node requires a connected lidar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54587/reading-message-once-subscribed-to-a-topic/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, exactly like you said: `data.ranges`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sample could should work.

void mapper_direct::laserCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg)
{
float theta = msg -> angle_min;
for(int i = 0; i < (int)(msg -> ranges.size()); i++)
{
//        ROS_INFO("Treating %dth laser from scan with value", i,msg->range[i]);

}
}

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-07**:
Not really as it looks like he's doing python. Also the ROS_INFO is missing %f and there's an empty `float r`.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-07**:
If its for python then its different but for C++ this should work ..